# How to store a character using JSTL <c:set>

Tags: java, jstl

I wanted to store a character value in a variable using the JSTL

My code to do this is:

```
<c:set var="letter" value='${param.colorLetter.toLowerCase().charAt(0)}' ></c:set>
```

Next i need to try and check if the character was 'v':

```
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${letter}=='v'">
                <lable>Color Name: </lable>Violet<br/>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
```

Currently I feel that it is not storing it as a Character Variable and so the test is failing. (No errors/exceptions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<c:set var="letter" value="${param.colorLetter.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toString()}" />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${letter eq 'v'}">
        <lable>Color Name: </lable>Violet<br/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

You have to put the whole test between `${}` and to add `toString()` after your `charAt(0)` to cast from `Character` to `String`.

Comment: Doing that throws the foll exception:

"Cannot convert 'v' of type class java.lang.String to java.lang.Long"

Comment: Can you copy/paste the value of `param.colorLetter`?

Comment: I used "<c:out value="${letter}" ></c:out>" to display its content for debugging purpose. It appears to print it correctly as "v"

Comment: Can you try with `'${letter eq "v"}'` instead of yours (see the inversion of the quotes/doublequotes)?

Comment: The thing is that the Expression language uses the ASCII value of the character and so I can simply use the ASCII value in place of the 'v' and it works. However this is not so convenient.

Comment: You must be right. Last try: `.charAt(0).toString()`? Maybe the `Character` type that returns `.charAt()` is the problem, so specifying that you want a `String` instead could resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is useful to anyone else, I was able to solve this issue by using "sp00m" suggestion.

```
<c:set var="letter" value='${param.colorLetter.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toString()}' ></c:set>
```

The Expression language was storing it as a character and then evaluating it would have to involve comparing the ascii values. The above method converts the Character to a String and then stores it in the "letter" variable. Then it's only a matter of simple String comparison:

```
<c:when test='${letter=="v"}'>
```